# Mule Jersey MultiPart 1.6 is not removed after undeployment

Tags: mule

i have created mule rest services with file upload functionality . i am using jersey multi part jar in my project . when i undeploy my application , it is not able to delete the folder saying Jersey-Multipart.jar is in use .

Please help .

Here is the [Link](http://www.javaroots.com/2013/05/createfileuploadmulejerseyrest.html) which i am using for creating file upload functionality in mule.

Answer (score 0):

Stop Mule standalone then you will be able to delete it.

Comment: but why do i need to stop mule for that . there are other applications running also . my other applications are getting undeployed cleanly . what is the problem in this ?

Comment: are you sure none of the others are using the jars? If not at least stoping Mule once will help you find the cause of locking issue.

Comment: i have tried deploying only this app in mule standalone ..when i tried to undeploy it , it failed with error message could not delete the jersey-multipart-1.6.jar . I getting the request as input stream and sending the response as output stream . But this error occurs without serving any request .

Comment: what timeouts do you have, can you share your flow?

Comment: i have used the same code which is there in the link i have provided in the question . Is it bug of mule ?

Comment: hard to say, can you run a test on that file to see what service is locking it? you could try redeploy it under a different name.